Trying to use Matplotlib, but it doesn't work even with downgraded Numpy version
I'm trying to import Matplotlib, but I keep getting import error with the following message:
If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

This is the version my the packages installed (using pip list):
matplotlib        3.9.0
matplotlib-inline 0.1.7
numpy             1.26.4
Anyone know how I can fix this import error?
Tried uninstalling both the packages and installing compatible versions, but error still persisted.
Deleted my virtual environment and installed the correct version in a clean new environment, error still persisted.
Expected the error to get fixed, and Matplotlib to get imported.

Only Numpy 2.0 can originate your error message. Check with import numpy; numpy.version.short_version from the same shell that gives you an import error on Matplotlib.

Matplotlib 3.9 is built against Numpy 2.0, so shouldn't cause an issue.  Perhaps some other package version you have is not Numpy2-ready.
